# Dependency issue while upgrading to Angular 9 for jodit-angular

Tags: angular, angular9, zone.js, jodit

Getting the below error while trying to run the command `npm install` after the angular migration to version 9.

Error

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: jodit-angular@1.9.4
npm ERR! Found: zone.js@0.10.3
npm ERR! node_modules/zone.js
npm ERR!   peer zone.js@"~0.10.3" from @angular/core@9.1.13
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!     @angular/core@"^9.1.13" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/core@"9.1.13" from @angular/animations@9.1.13 
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!       @angular/animations@"^9.1.13" from the root project       
npm ERR!       2 more (@angular/platform-browser, jodit-angular)
npm ERR!     11 more (@angular/cdk, @angular/common, @angular/forms, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer zone.js@"~0.9.1" from jodit-angular@1.9.4
npm ERR! node_modules/jodit-angular
npm ERR!   jodit-angular@"1.9.4" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: zone.js@0.9.1
npm ERR! node_modules/zone.js
npm ERR!   peer zone.js@"~0.9.1" from jodit-angular@1.9.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/jodit-angular
npm ERR!     jodit-angular@"1.9.4" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

I have added the required `zone.js` deps version and updated the `jodit-angular` as below.

The current version of node.js is 16.17.1

Package.json

```
  {
  "name": "Angular App",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16.0.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/core": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/localize": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/router": "^9.1.13",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.134",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "date-fns": "^1.29.0",
    "decimal.js": "^10.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.7",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "typeface-open-sans": "0.0.54",
    "jodit-angular": "1.9.4",
    "jsonpath": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-parallel": "^0.3.1",
    "ng-bullet": "^1.0.3",
    "ngx-cookie": "~5.0.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.15",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.1.15",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.1.13",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.7.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "2.0.1",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "puppeteer": "^1.17.0",
    "sonar-scanner": "^3.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^9.1.13",
    "@types/date-fns": "^2.6.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.3.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "https-proxy-agent": "^2.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "3.9.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "7.0.0",
    "karma": "4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.1.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "3.3.0",
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "fsevents": "^2.1.2"
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: try deleting your node_modules and npm i --force

Comment: @MehyarSawas I have tried this method. But couldn’t help me..

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that `jodit-angular@1.9.4` requires `zone.js@~0.9.1`, however you've specified `zone.js@~0.10.3` in your configuration.

Therefore, the solution is to downgrade the Zone.js version in your `package.json`:

```json
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if you insist on an incompatible version of Zone.js and want to override the corresponding dependency of `jodit-angular`, you can do that in your `package.json`:

```json
{
  ...
  "overrides": {
    "jodit-angular": {
      "zone.js": "$zone.js" // means: use the version from my project instead of the one you want
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution would be to remove both **jodit-angular@1.9.4** and **zone.js@~0.10.3** from your package.json and try npm install. After installation of npm, you can then add them manually to your project with the latest version.

> npm i jodit-angular@1.12.5

> npm i zone.js@0.10.3

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the version of the `jodit-angular@1.9.4`. Currently, `jodit-angular` developers removed the support for this library. So the only option is to upgrade the Angular version to 10 or we can fix the `jodit-angular` library issues and push the changes.